# Is there any workaround for using `export` field to load a package in Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have just found out that Webpack 4 doesn't respect `exports` field in `package.json`, as shown in this issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9509

Is there any workaround for this issue? I found out that my [package](https://github.com/winston0410/glory) doesn't work in `create-react-app`, as its `react-script` is using Webpack 4.44.

Is there anything I can do to make my package works for Webpack 4? How shoud I update my package.json config?

```json
{
    "name": "glory",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "author": "Hugo Sum",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "commonjs",
    "files": [
        "dist/"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npx rollup -c",
        "dev": "npx rollup -c -w",
        "test": "npx jest",
        "test:coverage": "npx jest --coverage",
        "test:watch": "npx jest --watch",
        "prepublish": "yarn build",
        "analyze": "npx deoptigate -r esm src/preset.js",
        "size": "npx size-limit",
        "size:analyze": "npx size-limit --why"
    },
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/index.js"
        },
        "./helper": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/helper.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/helper.js"
        },
        "./jsx": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/addon/jsx.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/addon/jsx.js"
        },
        "./virtual": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/addon/virtual.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/addon/virtual.js"
        },
        "./prefixer": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/addon/prefixer.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/addon/prefixer.js"
        },
        "./hydration": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/addon/hydration.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/addon/hydration.js"
        },
        "./keyframes": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/addon/keyframes.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/addon/keyframes.js"
        },
        "./global": {
            "require": "./dist/cjs/addon/global.js",
            "default": "./dist/esm/addon/global.js"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@blackblock/joli-string": "^1.1.0",
        "css-in-js-utils": "^3.1.0",
        "inline-style-prefixer": "^6.0.0",
        "is-in-browser": "^2.0.0",
        "safe-is-obj": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.13.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "7.12.13",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
        "@jest-runner/electron": "3.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "17.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "11.2.0",
        "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "4.10.1",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.20",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.17.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.17.0",
        "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
        "benchmark": "2.1.4",
        "chai": "4.3.3",
        "cross-blob": "2.0.0",
        "deoptigate": "0.5.0",
        "esbuild": "0.9.0",
        "eslint": "7.21.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "7.2.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "16.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-chai-expect": "2.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-chai-friendly": "0.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-const-immutable": "2.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-mocha": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "5.0.0",
        "esm": "3.2.25",
        "husky": "5.1.3",
        "jest": "26.6.3",
        "lint-staged": "10.5.4",
        "nyc": "15.1.0",
        "ramda": "0.27.1",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-is": "17.0.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
        "rollup": "2.41.1",
        "rollup-plugin-multi-input": "1.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "0.30.0",
        "size-limit": "4.10.1",
        "tiny-worker": "2.3.0",
        "tslib": "2.1.0",
        "typescript": "4.2.3",
        "url-polyfill": "1.1.12",
        "workerpool": "6.1.2"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "**/*.js": [
            "npx prettier --write"
        ]
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "npx lint-staged",
            "pre-push": "yarn test"
        }
    },
    "keywords": [
        "css",
        "style",
        "styles",
        "pico",
        "nano",
        "lite",
        "react",
        "js",
        "in-js",
        "css-in-js",
        "styled",
        "component",
        "styled-components",
        "jsxstyle",
        "rule",
        "stylesheet"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I also hit this problem and as the latest comment  (by webpack team member) in that issue said "exports works only for webpack v5, v4 is not supported this"